# Aluminum Oxide + Epsom salt ⮕ aluminum sulphate + Magnesium oxide

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

I was wondering that if you wrapped some Epsom salt in aluminum foil and set it on fire would you get aluminum sulphate and magnesium oxide, I couldn't find anything about this on the internet

Comment: OK, I'll bite.  How do you expect alumina to take $\ce{SO3}$ away from magnesia when the latter is a much stronger (Lux-Flood) base?

Comment: I thought that because Oxygen is much more reactive than Sulphur the oxygen atoms will go to the magnesium one and the Sulphur atom will go to the aluminum atom

Comment: You will get magnesium and aluminium oxides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aluminum oxide does not react with sulphates, even at high temperature. Anyway, aluminum sulphate does not support high temperatures : it is easily decomposed at around 700°C.